# How to gather user opinions via a survey based on tagging?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I'm completely new to Drupal, and am hoping it can help me with this job without me having to do too much tweaking.

I'm looking to gather user opinions on different subjects, but would rather not do it with a regular questionnaire type survey. I'm looking for something which would allow users to select topics and simply tag them with whichever words they find appropriate.

Does anyone know of a feature like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with taxonomy free tagging

Step 1 : Create a vocab, going at admin/structure/taxonomy/add
check the screen shot after adding a vocabulary named as survey.
[image]

Step 2: Create custom content type,going at admin/structure/types/add

Step 3: Add taxonomy term reference field to it.Check the settings in screen shot
[image]

once you click on save it will take you to next config page,where you will be choosing the vocab you created in step 1
[image]

Clicking field settings will take you now to last configuration page as in screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to combine the module [Webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform) with terms, but you could try. (There is also a module that adds a pre-built option lists of vocabulary terms to be used in Webform 3.x - [Webform Term Options](https://drupal.org/project/webform_term_opts).)

It is easy to set up different surveys with the [webform module](https://drupal.org/project/webform). Here is an example on youtube:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qIydHdxNx0&t=28m31s